# How do I clear the background of an SWT ExpandBar?

Tags: java, swt

The default background of an ExpandBar in SWT appears to be a gradient of whichever color the operating system is using.

However, when I change the background of an ExpandBar in SWT, the controls switch to the Windows Classic style.

Is there a way to set the background of the ExpandBar without reverting to the Windows Classic look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done without painting over the controls.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one:
[Control.setBackgroundImage(Image)](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#setBackgroundImage%28org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image%29)?